# passing php variables with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, amazon-s3

I've been trying to get php to rename an image in an `S3 bucket`. There's three stages

1. upload image (you can see a previous question I asked to see my
   solution to that) I've included the code I used below.
2. Use ajax to take the name I want for a file (the user ID) and
   pass it to a PHP renaming script.
3. run the renaming script.

Step two is giving me problems. If i hard code the names into the PHP script then it will find the source file and rename it. 
However I can't get it to rename the files using variables drawn from the page.

Here's the **HTML** button code

```
            <input type="file" id="file-chooser" />
        <button onclick= "pass()" id="upload-button">Upload to S3</button>
        <div id="results"></div>
```

Here's the **JS** code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'MY BUCKET'}});

                        var fileChooser = document.getElementById('file-chooser');
                        var button = document.getElementById('upload-button');
                        var results = document.getElementById('results');
                                            button.addEventListener('click', function() {


                            var file = fileChooser.files[0];
                            if (file) {
                                results.innerHTML = '';
                            var filename = file.name;
                                var params = {Key: file.name, ContentType: file.type, Body: file};
                                bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {

                                    results.innerHTML = err ? 'ERROR!' : 'UPLOADED';
                                    ajax_post();
                                });
                            } else {
                                results.innerHTML = 'Nothing to upload.';
                            }
                        }, false);

                        function pass() {
                            $.get("test.php");
                            return false;
                        }

                        function ajax_post() {
var ref = new 

Firebase("https://MY FIREBASE .firebaseio.com/");
            var authData = ref.getAuth();

                            // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
                            var fileChooser = document.getElementById('file-chooser');
                            var file = fileChooser.files[0];
                            var filename = file.name;
var userID = authData.uid;


                            var userID = USERS USER ID;
                            //alert($(this).attr('id'));
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: 'test.php',
                                data:  { userID : userID },
                                data: { filename : filename },
                                success: function (data) {
                                    alert("success!");
                                }
                            };
                            pass();
                        }

                    </script>
```

Here's the PHP.

```
    <?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;


$sourceBucket = "MY BUCKET";
$sourcename1 = $_POST['filename'];
$targetKeyname = $_POST['userID'];
$targetBucket = "MY BUCKET";


$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => "MY KEY",
    'secret' => "MY SECRET KEY"
));

$s3->copyObject(array(
    'Bucket'     => $targetBucket,
    'Key'        => $targetKeyname,
    'CopySource' => "{$sourceBucket}/{$sourcename}",
));

?>
```

**EDITING TO ADD**
I've been running test after test. If I hard code the variables into the PHP file it works. If I hard code the variables into the JS script it fails. The ajax is running the php file it's just not passing the variables to it. I've tried with and without the ISSET on the PHP side it just fails to take in the variables each time.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you got any error on calling ajax, See developer console to see error

Comment: No. There's no errors. I've tried testing every poart individually. So for example the user ID comes from a firebase call. I can get it to display to screen and pass it into a JS variable. 
The PHP script runs perfectly if I run it by itself and just have the variables hard coded into it. 
I tried creating a separate PHP file to store the variables in. I thought that maybe when I ran the ajax post it would place the variables in my PHP file but when I chose to run it, the variables would be wiped. That failed to work too. 

I think i've run out of troubleshooting steps that I can perform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the issue was. It was Firebase. Firebase was returning the values I required however the PHP script was retrieving an error from AWS. I had assumed that the AJAX was failing to pass the value on but I was only half right. the AJAX failed because it didn't have the value at that point. I added in a 3 second delay before the upload occurs and it works fine. Firebase was just slower than the PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is your issue `var userID = USERS USER ID;` I'm not sure where that information is coming from. But without seeing the html/js where that is derived from, its difficult to determine the problem.

If its text input with an id of userID, it should be something like:

```
<input type="text" name="userID" id="userID">
```

js:

```
var userID = $("#userID").val();
```

**AJAX Update**

merge `BOTH` data into one object:

```
                        data:  { userID : userID },
                        data: { filename : filename },
```

**will become**

```
data:  { userID : userID , filename : filename },
```

Comment: I added in three extra lines to the code above. I'm storing the user ID's in firebase and I'm pulling them from there. I can get the firebase ID to print to a DIV on the screen so I know the FB call is working.

Comment: just to add. I tried hard coding the filename and user id into the javascript. I changed var filename = "IMAGE NAME"; and var userID = "jhghjghjmnbv"; to that random garble to see if it would pass those through and rename the file to the garbage name. It failed.

Comment: I do see an issue with your AJAX call. I updated my answer, but basically merge the two `data` parameters into one.

Comment: I tried that. It didn't work but I've left it the way you suggested so that doesn't cause future errors.
Can you think of a workaround for it? I'm thinking maybe storing the variables in a separate json file.